# Serial Number For Telerik Grid in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

I need to add a column to telerik grid which shows the serials number Please Help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bound column if the serial number is a regular property exposed by the object the grid is bound to:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<MyObject>()
        .Name("MyGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
           columns.Bound(o => o.SerialNumber);
        });
%>
```

If you need some custom formatting applied you can define a template for that column:

```
<%  Html.Telerik().Grid<MyObject>()
        .Name("MyGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
           columns.Bound(o => o.SerialNumber).Template(o =>
           {
             %>
               <strong><%= o.SerialNumber %></strong>
             <%
           });
        })
        .Render();
%>
```

And finally if you are using ajax or web service binding and need customization - use the ClientTemplate:

```
 <%  Html.Telerik().Grid<MyObject>()
            .Name("MyGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
               columns.Bound(o => o.SerialNumber)
                      .ClientTemplate("<strong><#= SerialNumber #></strong>");
            })
            .Render();
    %>
```